# Do I have to create a router for every page (component) I create?

Tags: angular

I create a router into my proyect

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Documentacion', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/documentacion/documentacion.module').then(m => m.DocumentacionModule) },
  { path: 'Main', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo:'Main' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

but it doesn't work, even if I try creating anchors with router-link or typing the url, the site redirects me to home, or in case the url is ok then the page doesn't load

I tried then creating a router for every page I created and then puf, it worked.

is it mandatory for angular to create a router module for every page (component) I create?

thanks you all

I followed Angular documentation page that talks about router (https://angular.io/guide/router), but it doesn't seems the need to create a router for every page, but the project I created before this one I saw that I was doing so to make it work

**UPDATE 1**
Hi there, I update with the code in

documentacio-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DocumentacionComponent } from './documentacion.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: DocumentacionComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DocumentacionRoutingModule { }
```

what I've figure out is that on the app-routing I wrote forRoot, but in the page I wrote forChild, is it ok to be that way so?

Comment: From the code you posted it's hard to see any problem with it. It's certainly possible to declare multiple routes (and views) inside of a single router.

Comment: Each Module that is loaded using loadChildren need his own "routers".NOTE: See that should be `imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],...`, this [part of the docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) it's more clearer than your link

Comment: Hi there Eliseo and thank you very much for your help, I've read the link you left, but I couldn't figure out reading it, in other hand, I noticed what you mentioned about forChild and found that I've wrote it. Is it mandatory to be that way?

Comment: Hello there Mike and thank you very much for your assistance too, I've updated my question with some page's code

Comment: @matiasgabrielTommasi, use lazy loading is about not load the full application, but it's not good each component was loaded in "lazy mode". Generally you use lazy loaded when the user not use a series of routers. Imagine an app with a part of "Admin" (only allowed to users authenticates) or has a part of "config" (a series of tables or parameters) or has a part of graphics with a dependency of a big library or has a tutorial that generally the user only see the first time or.... NOTE: yes, each "loadChildren", the router should be add using `forChild()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figure it out by reading your answers, I think my question was satisfied